# InitializeSimpleMembershipAttribute returns TargetInvocationException

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-membership, forms-authentication

I am still a relatively inexperience with Visual Studios and C# so please let me know if necessary information has not been provided or I am unclear in my description.

I have an MVC 4 project in Visual Studio 2010 Web Developer Express and I am attempting to set up basic Forms Authentication.  I have used the ASP.NET Configuration Manager to set up a couple test users and roles.  The Configuration Manager has also created the ASPNETDB.MDF database in my App_data folder which has been included in the project.

I am currently using the generated AccountController and Account views.

Whenever I attempt to access a HTTPGET or HTTPPOST method with which has the [Authorize] attribute, a TargetInvocationException is thrown from the following method in the InitializeSimpleMembershipAttribute class:

```
public override void OnActionExecuting(ActionExecutingContext filterContext) 
{
    // Ensure ASP.NET Simple Membership is initialized only once per app start 
    LazyInitializer.EnsureInitialized(ref _initializer, ref _isInitialized, ref _initializerLock);
}
```

When viewing the details of the exception, the inner exception states that "The ASP.NET Simple Membership Database could not be initialized."

The inner exception of the above inner exception states that it "Could not find the conceptual model type for" a given model.

The model that was not found belongs to an ADO.Net [.edmx] file which is generated from a database.  The model that it cannot find is alphabetically the first table/class in the database, so it likely also applies for every class from that database.

I am not sure if it is important, but I use a database separate from the ASPNETDB.MDF to store information enter on the website.

I do not understand why the LazyInitializer.EnsureInitialized() method may be causing this problem.

Answer (score 0):

Have you checked the connection string used by `WebSecurity.InitializeDatabaseConnection` in `Global.asax.cs` `Application_Start()` - this could potentially cause the issue.

If the named connections string is correct are you sure the dbContext connection string is correct:

```
public SomeContext(): base("MyConnectionStringName")
{
}
```

Comment: There is no WebSecurity.InitializeDatabaseConnection in Global.asax.cs.  I am using an edmx, so I have not written the dbContext.  An example of the generated methods in the entities class that I use as opposed to a dbContext is `public DatabaseEntities() : base ("name=DatabaseEntities", "DatabaseEntities") { }`

Comment: is the DatabaseEntities connection string the one that points to the database that contains the SimpleMembership tables (webpages_Membership etc) - as you mentioned that you use two databases - it must have been at one point or the entities wouldn't be there, but maybe it's changed?

Comment: No it isn't.  The DatabaseEntities connection points to a database which stores information entered on the website.  It contains information about business models that are entered and modified by users.  This database is working perfectly fine.  However, the `ASPNETDB.MDF` database was recently added by the ASP.Net Configuration Manager and this one contains user account data.  My problem is that when the `LazyInitializer.EnsureInitialized()` is run (the one mentioned in the OP), it fails to find a 'conceptual model type' for a class which is defined by the DatabaseEntities db.